# Undefined index: homePageLink

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this PHP warning:

```
Message: Undefined index: homePageLink
```

The index is there.  I can print it within the function and even when it gets through to the view if I `print_f` I can see it.

```
function logo($params) {
  $widgetData['title'] = $params['title'] == "" ? ROOT_DOMAIN : $params['title'];
  $widgetData['homePageLink'] = $params['homePageLink'] ? "http://" . ROOT_DOMAIN : false;
  return $widgetData;
}
```

If I print `$params` within the logo function I get:

```
$params ([homePageLink] => 1 [title] => My Title)
```

and I get exactly the same if I `print_f` the Array in the View.

I have a ton of these functions doing exactly the same thing and this is the first time I have had this.  I have tried changing the "homePageLink" entry to a String as opposed to a Boolean but it makes no difference.

I get the data from a JSON file:

```
{
  "logo": {
   "homePageLink" : true,
   "title": "My Title"
}
```

Am I going mad?

UPDATE: I forgot to say that I had already tried:

```
$widgetArray = array();
```

Comment: where you defined $widgetArray in function logo() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Last Update:*
I deduce from your comment to Rakesh's answer (*When I do this it works fine: `if (isset($params['homePageLink'])) echo "IT IS SET TO: " . $params['homePageLink'];` I get "IT IS SET TO: 1"*), that you are, in fact not checking if the given key is set.
Like I said countless times all over this post (in comments, *and* in this answer): ***add `isset` checks whenever you access any key in the `$params` array***.

Don't just check this `isset` business once, you have to check every key, whenever you use it, or fill in the missing keys with a default value:

```
fucntion logo(array $params)
{
    if (!isset($params['homePageLink']))
        $params['homePageLink'] = false;//set to false as default
    if (!isset($params['title']))
        $params['title'] = false;
}
```

Now you're certain that the keys you need are, indeed, set.

*update*
So, it turns out you tried declaring the `$widgetData` array up-front, to no avail. Ok, so a quick recap of things to check, still:

- Check for typo's, both in the actual code, and in your tests!
- Add a type-hint to your `logo` function, to ensure `$params` is always an array.
- Add `isset` checks to all keys in the `$params` array you are trying to use (as shown below)
- Check the keys of `$params`, making sure they aren't binary strings, which might contain invisible `\0` chars (like when casting instances of [objects to an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting))

It might be possible the notice isn't coming from your accessing `$params['homePageLink']`, but rather your trying to assign to the `$widgetData` variable.
Seeing as you did not explicitly declared the latter as an array, you *should* get a notice. Try changing your `logo` function to something along the lines of:

```
function logo(array $params)
{//use type-hints, to ensure $params is an array
    $widgetData = array(
        'title' => isset($params['title']) && $params['title'] ? $params['title'] : ROOT_DOMAIN,
        'homePageLink' => isset($params['homePageLink']) && $params['homePageLink'] ? 'http://'.ROOT_DOMAIN : false
    );
    //do stuff
    return $widgetData;
}
```

Of course, if all you do is construct the `$widgetData`array, you needn't even bother assigning it to a local variable, and just write

```
return array(
    'title' => 'same code as above'
);
```

If any of the values in `$params` might be `null` at any given point, then neither `empty` nor `isset` will be of much use (`isset` evaluates to `false`, and `empty` evaluates to `true` if an array key is assigned `null`). So when a value is null, the key *does* exist, even though both of these checks will tell you it doesn't.
In that case, there's only one thing for it:

```
if (array_key_exists('title', $params))
{//$params['title'] can be null, false, 0, an empty string... whatever, but the KEY exists
    //do stuff with $params['title']
}
```

Comment: Yes I could have done that.  Many of the other Functions perform tasks first but this one doesn't so I could do that on this occasion, thank you.

Comment: @Andy: Check my last update, and be thorough: check all of the code that interacts with the `$params` array. Add type-hinting to the function's signature, and set to debugging... it's part of programming, just as much as writing code is (in most cases, you'll spend more time debugging and refactoring or re-writing code, even). PS: Accepting someones answer would be a kind gesture on your part, too. You've only accepted 1 answer on SO so far, and it was your own. Some people might take that the wrong way, besides: accepting an answer gives you +2 rep points

Comment: Elias, thanks for your comments.  The odd thing is that on this occasion I KNOW that the keys are set as I can print_f the $params array and see them.  I will wrap my code in the right checks but am frustrated by the error when I know it is set AND I use the value in the View as a conditional and it works fine.  Very odd.

Comment: @Andy: on occasion, the keys might be set, true enough, but that doesn't mean that they'll be set _every time_ the function is called. You could add `if (!isset($params['homePageLink'])) throw new RuntimeException('not set');` and check the stack trace, to find where the function was called from, and uncover the piece of code that is calling your function with a malformed array. Also look into using Xdebug, to step through your code. It's one of the most valuable tools at your disposal.

Comment: @Elias:  Thanks for that, I appreciate it. I will check out XDebug too.

Comment: @Elias: I have just added the following code:

if (array_key_exists('homePageLink', $params)) {
$widgetData['homePageLink'] = $params['homePageLink'] ? "http://" . ROOT_DOMAIN : false;
}

Nothing else has changed but the error has stopped!  Very very odd!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: *to fix the function, I used the php [empty()](http://php.net/empty) function*

```
function logo($params) {
  $widgetData['title'] = (!empty($params['title']) ? ROOT_DOMAIN : $params['title']);
  $widgetData['homePageLink'] = (!empty($params['homePageLink']) ? "http://" . ROOT_DOMAIN : false);
  return $widgetData;
}
```

I tested it like this:

```
define('ROOT_DOMAIN', 'test.com');

var_dump(logo(array(
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'homePageLink' => 1
)));
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: why use a _function_, when there's a far better _language construct_ at hand, in the form of `isset`? `empty($array['keyOfFalsyValue'])` evaluates to true, even though the key does really exist!

Answer (score 0):

Set variables initially with blank values or as an array` like:-

```
$widgetData = array();
```

also you can use `empty()` or `isset()` for avoid notices

```
$widgetData['homePageLink'] = (!empty($params['homePageLink']) ? "http://" . ROOT_DOMAIN : false);
```

or

```
$widgetData['homePageLink'] = ($params['homePageLink'] == true) ? "http://" . ROOT_DOMAIN : false);
```

Comment: use `isset` here, not `empty`, and the notice is probably the result of the OP not declaring `$widgetData` as an array in the first place

Comment: `isset($params['homePageLink'])` evaluates to `true`, even if the value assigned to `$params['homePageLink']` is `false`. cf my answer: check with `isset` + evaluate the value itself. Short circuit evaluation ensures no notices

Comment: You might want to read [this blog post](http://kunststube.net/isset/) on the details/caveats and gotcha's of `empty`. You're likely to use it far less after reading through it

Comment: yeah isset() not working in this case but uses more cases for avoid notices or check var set

Comment: When I do this it works fine:  if (isset($params['homePageLink'])) echo "IT IS SET TO: " . $params['homePageLink']; I get "IT IS SET TO: 1"

Comment: Elias, I tried setting $widgetData to a blank array before anything else but I still get the error.  The thing is, on this occasion, the parameter does exist and is set to true.

Comment: @Andy: And did you also include `isset` checks whenever you use `$param`? As I said in my answer: _"add isset checks to all keys in the `$params` array you are trying to use"_. If you get a notice, that means you aren't using `isset`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
function logo($params) {
  $widgetData = array();
  $widgetData['title'] = $params['title'] == "" ? ROOT_DOMAIN : $params['title'];
  $widgetData['homePageLink'] = empty($params['homePageLink']) ? "http://" . ROOT_DOMAIN : false;
  return $widgetData;
}
```

Comment: @Andy: long shot, but have you checked if the array keys of `$params` aren't binary strings, containing the invisible \0 char?

Comment: Hmmm! How I do that Elias?